# Do Federal Pacific baseboard heaters have a reputation for poor quality?

Tags: electrical, heating

I know Federal Pacific is infamous for their American Stab-Lok panels which should be replaced on sight.  However, this panel is Cutler-Hammer CH type (the narrow 3/4" breakers).

It's the 240V electric baseboard heaters that are Federal Pacific.   There's a 2000W heater, and three 1000W heaters (all sharing a 30A breaker).

Is this something I should be worried about?

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I have ever had with FPE base board heaters is the thermostat. I am not saying there was a flaw. The contacts fail after many years of service and have required replacement. Your total of 5000 watts would be 20.8A so a 30 Amp breaker would be normal with #10 wire supplying them. If you cannot find a replacement thermostat (for the ones in the base board) I have added a wall mounted thermostat for the room and bypassed the thermostat but not the over temp sensor that is a safety if the contacts weld closed in the thermostat. Added Today I just did a power survey on an older 25kva 480 to 240-120v transformer that has been in use for? It wal lightly loaded at 54A at 240. I increased its load to 91A at 240 even ballanced loads (120) and it is still running cool on a hot day here (mid 90's) so I would still say FPE products other than "stab lock" are good.

Comment: Well, none of them seem to work (the thermostat clicks but they don't get warm) so that would certainly explain it.  I'd be tempted to go with 24V thermostat (adding  a contactor) for better regulation and future-proofing.  Also they are secondary heat, there's a gas furnace too, so it's perfect for the Nest's auxiliary heat feature.

Comment: You will would need more than just a contactor.  A 240v to 24v transformer seems like an oddity to me, especially not having a neutral.  I think I'd just buy new baseboard heaters.

Comment: @Kris -- 208/240 to 24VAC transformers are common in industrial control panel applications (I have a used 208/240/480 to 24VAC transformer myself, got it at a junk-giveaway)

Comment: @ThreephaseEel, and no neutral required?

Comment: @Kris -- nope, no neutral required, as you could be dealing with a 240 or 480 delta system for the panel power.

Comment: I was more thinking of sourcing 24V from an entirely different circuit.

Comment: The FPE Baseboards I have repaired were all 240. If you have maybe a newer model, The ones I remember were from the late 60's or early 70's. I have FPE Transformers at my plant 480/240 at 3 or 4 places from 15-25 KVA and these work as well as any other units. I check all the transformers regularly and we have IR scans done yearly so other than the "stab lock" breakers/ panels I have not had any issues with there products.

Comment: If this is a home in the U.S. 3 phase delta will not be there in my experiance and based on code for most of my years as an electrician. Deltas have a wild leg and from my understanding of the code this shall not be allowed in a home but is in comercial or industrial instillations.

Comment: @EdBeal -- you can have 120/208/240 high leg delta service to a dwelling unit; however, the uses of the high leg are severely restricted by 210.6(A) as you can't run lights or cord-and-plug stuff < 1.5kW on it.  (I don't believe you can heavily load it anyway, so it winds up sitting unused in the panel?)

Comment: @EdBeal -- (although the comment on the no-neutral transformers was for industrial control panels where straight 240 or 480 delta would be coming in)